# Can I run the extension file immediately when I click without downloading an attachment?

Tags: wcf

Currently in Chrome browsers, when an attachment is clicked, it is automatically downloaded, but what I want to do is not saved when the attachment is clicked. (e.g. windows communication foundation = wcf)

Comment: What does this question have to do with WCF?

Comment: Is this possible with wcf?

Comment: WCF is a service layer technology, not a frontend tool. basically you can use anything to serve your data. but the question of how the data is being treated in UI is whole different thing and does not fall under the realm of WCF.

Comment: Is there another way without wcf??

Comment: You seem to be at the starting stage of the software development journey. My advice is to go through the fundamentals of the platform you wanna utilize and learn the basics of web and HTTP first. The obvious will be demystified automatically.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Share your code and please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.